# Running conduit from an old rectangular 2 x 3 exterior box?

Tags: electrical

I have an old 2” x 3” rectangular recessed electrical box recessed in aluminum siding, [image] which was standard back in 1972 when my home was built.

I am trying to figure out how I can use this box as a source to run conduit from it to a new outdoor light receptacle  several feet above it.

Is there an extension box made for these smaller old boxes that I could attach to it to run the conduit to the new box 2 feet above?

If not how would you recommend accomplishing what I’m trying to do ??
Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unscrew the light fixture on the cover of the box.

Screw in your conduit fitting.

Comment: They'd need to use a whip of flex (LFMC/LFNC) so that the conduit doesn't block access to the box

Answer (score 1):

There are exterior extension rings that have several threaded holes in them that fit 1/2" PVC conduit.

You would screw the extension ring to the existing box and then the existing light(assuming you still want it) or a blank cover to the front.

Out the top or sides you can pull 1/2" or in some cases (depends on manufacturer) 3/4" PVC conduit to run your new THHN in to the new light.

Something like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-3-4-in-Gray-1-Gang-6-Holes-Weatherproof-Extension-Ring-WSE675G/300845953